# While installing body-parser got an error of 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, post

I'm a beginner and as i was trying to install the body-parser package i got this issue what should I do in order to solve this problem?

```
D:\Calculator>npm install body-paeser
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/body-paeser - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'body-paeser@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-14T07_18_28_751Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Spell the package name correctly.  `body-paeser` is not `body-parser`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You typed it incorrect. use this

```
npm i body-parser
```